# What's the correct representation of projection matrix between $UU^T$ and $U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, projection, projection-matrices

I have seen those two representation of projection matrix $UU^T$ and $U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T$, where column of $U$ are orthonormal basis of subspace $S$. Which one is more accurate?

For projection matrix $UU^T$, $P_S(x)=UU^Tx$, then $x-UU^Tx$ is orthognal to any vector $y:=Uc\in S$, in the notes I read, it derive $||x-y||^2_2$ as:
$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
||x-y||^2_2&=&||x-UU^Tx+UU^Tx-y||^2_2 \\
&=& ||x-UU^Tx||^2_2+||UU^Tx-y||^2_2  \quad\textrm{By Pythagoras's theorem}\\
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

I couldn't solve the product of two vectors to zero. Here's how I derive the middle part:

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
(x-UU^Tx)(UU^Tx-y)^T &=& (x-UU^Tx)(UU^Tx)^T-y^T(x-UU^Tx) \\
&=&(x-UU^Tx)x^TUU^T - 0 \\
\end{eqnarray} 
$$
Where did I go wrong?

--Edit--

1. For orthonormal columns, $UU^T=UIU^T=U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T$, two equations are the same.
2. As pointed out by @user1551 Dot product has a scaler result,so the equation should be:
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray} 
   (x-UU^Tx)^T(UU^Tx-y) &=& (x-UU^Tx)^T(UU^Tx)-(x-UU^Tx)^Ty \\
   &=&(x^TUU^Tx-x^TUU^TUU^Tx)- 0 \\
   &=& x^TUU^Tx-x^TUU^Tx = 0
   \end{eqnarray} 
   $$

Comment: Two things are wrong in your question. First, $UU^T$ in general is not a projection matrix. You need the columns of $U$ to be an **orthonormal** set of vectors, not merely an orthogonal one. Second, the dot product between $x-UU^Tx$ and $UU^Tx-y$ is $(x-UU^Tx)^T(UU^Tx-y)$, not $(x-UU^Tx)(UU^Tx-y)^T$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for your reply. First, that's a typo I didn't notice, I will edit it now. Second, actually I don't know why the first component should be transposed. What are the rules for that?

Comment: This is basic matrix multiplication. For any $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, $xy^T$ is the product of an $n\times1$ matrix and a $1\times n$ matrix. Hence the result is an $n\times n$ matrix. On the other hand, $x^Ty$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, which is equivalent to a scalar. Some people call the former an outer product and the latter an inner product.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for pointing out that for me. I have update the solution above.

Comment: @K For **any** matrix $U$ with linearly independent columns, the matrix of the projection onto the column space of $U$ is $P = U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T$. If the columns of $U$ are orthonormal, then this expression can be simplified: because $U$ has orthonormal columns, $U^TU = I$, which means that
$$
P = U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T = U(I)U^T = UU^T.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $s$ be the dimension of $S$ and $U$ be a $n\times s$ matrix whose colums form an orthonormal basis of $S$. This is the same as saying that :
$$U^T U = I_s$$
where $I_s$ is the $s\times s$ identity matrix.

Then, as OP shows, $P_S = U U^T = U (U^T U )^{-1} U^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and the orthogonal projection on $S$.

> I couldn't solve the product of two vectors to zero.

Since $y \in S$, there is $c\in \mathbb K^s$ such that $y = Uc$. Then :
\begin{align}
(x - UU^T x )\cdot (y - UU^T x) &= (x^T - x^TUU^T)U(c - U^T x) \\
&= (x^T U - x^TU(U^TU))(c-U^Tx) \\
&= (x^T U - x^TU)(c-U^Tx) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Now, if the columns of $U$ are not orthogonal, then $U^T U = I_s$ does not hold anymore and $UU^T$ is not a projection, since $(UU^T)^2 =  U(U^TU) U^T \neq UU^T$.

Given any $s\times n$ matrix $V$ such that $VU = I_s$ you can check that $P_{S,V} = UV$ is a projection onto $S$ (but not necessarily orthogonal). It is orthogonal if, and only if, $P_{S,V}^T = P_{S,V}$, which rewrites as :
\begin{align}
V^T U^T =UV &\Leftrightarrow U^T  = U^TUV \\
&\Leftrightarrow V = (U^TU)^{-1} U^T
\end{align}

So the orthogonal projection onto $S$ is :
$$P_{S,\perp} = U(U^TU)^{-1} U^T$$